# Ln of gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

Im having trouble with one step of the calculation of the derivative of the $\ln(\Gamma(z))$:
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}=ze^{\gamma z}\prod(1+\frac{z}{k})e^{-z/k},$$ then taking the logarithm of both sides I arrived at:$$\ln(\Gamma(z))=-\ln(z) - \gamma z - \sum \{ \ln(1+\frac{z}{k}) - \frac{z}{k} \} $$
but the correct expression is $$\ln(\Gamma(z))=-\ln(z) - \gamma z - \sum \ln\{ (1+\frac{z}{k}) - \frac{z}{k} \}$$ How works that step???

Comment: Your result looks correct to me.

Comment: What source tells you the latter is right? $\ln\{(1+z/k)-z/k\}=\ln1=0$.

Comment: According to [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogGammaFunction.html) your answer is correct.